# Loading a jquery function on form submit instead on change event

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery script that dynamically changes `select` menus. The script uses the function `populate()` everytime a change event occurs in one of the menus. I would like the same script to run after a `form` submit. To have an idea this is what the script looks like...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }

    function populate() {
        if ($('#STATEID').val() == 'AK' || $('#OB_USTATEID').val() == 'DC') {
            // Alaska and District Columbia have no counties
            $('#county_drop_down3').hide();
            $('#no_county_drop_down3').show();
        } 
        else {
            fetch.doPost('../../getCounties2c.php');
        }
    }

    $('#STATEID').change(populate);

    var fetch = function() {
        var counties = $('#countyid');
        return {
            doPost: function(src) {
                $('#loading_county_drop_down3').show(); // Show the Loading...
                $('#county_drop_down3').hide(); // Hide the drop down
                $('#no_county_drop_down3').hide(); // Hide the "no counties" message (if it's the case)

                if (src) 
                    $.post(src, { state_code3: $('#STATEID').val() },  this.getCounties);
                else 
                    throw new Error('No SRC was passed to getCounties!');
            },
            getCounties: function(results) {
                if (!results) 
                    return;

                var allCities = $("<option value=\"All\">All Counties</option>");
                counties.html(results);
                counties.prepend(allCities);
                var first = getUrlVars()["countyid"];
                if (first) { 
                    counties.val(first).attr('selected',true);
                }
                else {
                    counties.val("All").attr('selected',true);
                }

                $('#loading_county_drop_down3').hide(); // Hide the Loading...
                $('#county_drop_down3').show(); // Show the drop down
            }
        }
    }();

    populate();
});
```

How can I accomplish that? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: you mean after the submit event has occured or after the form has been submitted?

Comment: Then bind the function to the `submit` event of the form... what's the problem?

Comment: after the form has been submitted

Comment: the problem is that i am not actually experienced with javascript thats why i am asking you to give me a hand on how to do that

Comment: We would prefer that you not ask the same question more than once. Doing so will raise flags, question closure by mods or the community and if it happens too often your account will no longer be able to ask new questions. Next time edit your original question or perhaps offer a bounty. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(element).submit(function (e) {} );` to catch a submit event. You can even fire it off, by calling `$(element).submit()`.

jQuery docs : http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: So yoy mean that in my html declation i have to insert $(element).submit(function (e) {} ) and inside the brackets to have my script?

Comment: No, you add that in your JavaScript file. For example in the `$(doument).ready(function (e) {} );`.

Comment: can you please tell me how i have to exactly modify the given script coz i am driving crazy!! Thank you anyway for your effort helping me

Comment: Put the code given in the answer, with the form id as element, and put whatever code you want in the function.

Comment: Ok now i understand how it should be done.But in my script there is a function running everytime a change occurs in the select menu, how should i change it to populate the menus after the submitting of the form?

Comment: For example, `$('#myFormID').submit(function (e) {theFunctionIWantToCall() } );`

Comment: Yeah i got that part, but in my script as you see there is this   $('#STATEID').change(populate);  so i guess i have to modify somehow the script to populate the menu without the change event. Can you give me any advice on that part? Thanx again for heling me...

Comment: I don't know what your form ID is, but you can call `$('#myFormID').submit(populate);`, just like with the change event...